# How does $1+ \tan^2x =\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

I am unable to see why the following is true:  $$1+ \tan^2x =\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$$
I have looked into the topic and I am familiar with the reciprocal ratios of cosec, sec, and cot. but cannot derive how this statement makes sense.

Any help on the topic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $tan = sin/cos$ and $sin^2 + cos^2 = 1$,

Comment: Clear fractions. $\cos x\tan x=?$

Comment: For use as a reference and to supplement Ahmed's answer, see the Pythagorean identity: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already know that:

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

(And there are many videos showing this using a unit circle: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=o-fAx_96lgw)

Then you should have no problem seeing:

$$\tan^2+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$$

Because we just took the first equation and divided both sides by $\cos^2x$

Comment: I don't think belief has anything to do with this. I'd rather have OP *know for a fact* that $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$.

Comment: Thank you , this has been a tremendous help. I knew it would be something simple but could not quite understand it. The video is also very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Using $\tan(x)=\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}$ and the trigonometric identity you will be able to find the desired result 
$$1+\tan^2x=\frac {\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=\frac {1}{\cos^2x}$$

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

$$1+\tan^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(x)\left(1+\tan^2(x)\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(x)\left(1+\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)^2\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(x)\left(1+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(x)+\frac{\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it step by step, I Certainly understand the concept now so it will be much easier to build on this

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

How, exactly, are you **defining** these functions?  The very simplest is in terms of a right triangle in which "$cos(\theta)$" is defined as "length of near side" (leg closest to angle $\theta$) divided by the "length of the hypotenuse" and $tan(\theta)$ is defined as "length of opposite side divided by length of near side".   If we let "a" represent the length of the "opposite side", b the length of the "near side", and c the length of the "hypotenuse", then  the Pythagorean theorem says $a^2+ b^2= c^2$.  Divideb^ both sides by $b^2$ to get $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ 1= \frac{c^2}{b^2}$,
 $1+ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2= \left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^2$
 $1+ tan^2(\theta)= \frac{1}{cos^2(\theta)}$

Comment: Great, that has cleared things up for me. Thank you :)